# Disable click after clicking the textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, onclicklistener

I have a `TextView` and I put a `OnClickListener` on this `TextView`. I use this action to load custom view onto a `LinearLayout`.

But when I click on this `TextView` twice, custom view is repeating on the `LinearLayout`. I clear all custom views on this `LinearLayout` before I load new custom views on to this `LinearLaout`.

This is my `OnClickListener` on `TextView`,

```
TextView rejectedTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.roster_menu_rejected_title);

rejectedTitleTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                rejectedTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.acceptedPurpleColour));
                newTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.defaultBlack));
                acceptedTitleTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.defaultBlack));

                locationLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
                rosterBottomLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.d("CHECK_ACTION"," REJECTED_TEXT_VIEW ");

                InternetConnectivity internetConnectivity = new InternetConnectivity();
                final boolean isConnectedToInternet = internetConnectivity.isConnectedToInternet(context);

                if(isConnectedToInternet==true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1300);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    getDataFromServer("REJECTED");
                }else{
                        Snackbar.make(mainView, "No Internet Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

**getDataFromServer("REJECTED");**

is the method which I used to load custom view onto this `LinearLayout`.

How can I prevent this issue ?

Have any ideas ?

Comment: try it using boolean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside onclickListener put

```
rejectedTitleTextView.setClickable(false);
```

and once finish your functionality make it as true because u need to click for next time .

```
rejectedTitleTextView.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside `setOnclickListener` try below code:-

```
textView.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    rejectedTitleTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {  
                mSpinner.setEnabled(false); 
                 mSpinner.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public 
                 void run() {
                  mSpinner.setEnabled(true); }
                }
              //  do your stuff here
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain boolean value like this

```
    boolean isClick=false;

rejectedTitleTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!isClick)
            {
              //do your Stuff on onCLick
              isClick=true;
             }else
                  {
                    //leave it blank if you do not want to do anything second time
                        }
            }
        });
```